# objectdb select where query

Tags: where-clause, objectdb

I attempt to select some instance using where clause

```
public static List<RSSItem> getRSSItem(int x1, int x2) {
     EntityManagerFactory emf = DBHandler.getEmf();
    EntityManager em = DBHandler.getEm(emf);
    String query =
            "SELECT items FROM RSSItem items "
            + "WHERE items.id <= :x1 AND "
            + "items.id >= :x2";
    List<RSSItem> results =
            (List<RSSItem>) em.createQuery(query).
            setParameter("x1", x1).
            setParameter("x2", x2).
            getResultList();
    return results;
}
```

the RSSItem attributes :

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Long id;
String title;
String link;
String description;
String pubdate;
String content;
HashMap<String, Integer> keyword = new HashMap();
HashMap<String, Integer> keywordBefore = new HashMap();
// TreeMap <String, Integer> keyword = new TreeMap();
String feed;
```

the problem is it always return a list with 0 size. what's wrong with my select query?

Comment: What are you passing in as x1 and x2?

Comment: I called a function 

    `List<RSSItem> berita = RSSItem.getRSSItems(1, 500);`

so when it passed, x1 supposed to be 1 and x2 is 500.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the values `x1 = 1` and `x2 = 500`, the query turns into...

```
SELECT items FROM RSSItem items
 WHERE items.id <= 1 
   AND items.id >= 500
```

Since no id's are `less or equal to 1` and `greater or equal to 500` at the same time, the query will give no hits. What you want is probably;

```
String query =
        "SELECT items FROM RSSItem items "
        + "WHERE items.id >= :x1 AND "
        + "items.id <= :x2";
```

...which with your example data will find all id's between 1 and 500, inclusive.